# Aligning my base with HTML5/ CSS

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, alignment

I am a beginner Web Designer and have some basic questions for those of you who can help. I am designing a portfolio site and I just can't seem to get the base of it aligned how I would like it.

Here is what I want: 
https://imageshack.com/i/0xovibp

And it is not looking like that. Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="graphic design, art direction, portfolio, toronto, design, branding, Mira Metter, St. Joseph Media, editorial">
<meta name="description" content="design">

<title>Portfolio site</title>

<link href="mainhome4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="top"> 

    <div id="banner">   
</div>

 <div id="nav-menu"><nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav></div>
<a href="index4.html"><img class="logo" src="images/mira-logo.png" alt="mira-logo"></a>

  </div>

<section id="home">

 <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="FlashID" title="homesmoke2">
<param name="movie" value="video/homesmoke2.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0">
<!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
<param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
<param name="BGCOLOR" value="#FFFFFF">
<!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object data="video/homesmoke2.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <param name="quality" value="high">
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
  <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0">
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
  <param name="BGCOLOR" value="#FFFFFF">
  <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
  <div>
    <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
  </div>
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
</section>

<footer>

<h3> <a href="contact.html">contact me</a></h3>

<img class="arrow" src="images/arrow.png" alt="arrow">

<nav><ul>
<li><img class="social-media"src="images/pinterest.png" alt="pinterest"></li>
<li><img class="social-media" src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter"></li>
<li><img class="social-media" src="images/instgram.png" alt="instagram"></li>
<li><img class="social-media" src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></li>
</ul></nav>

</footer>  


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */

/* Header/ Navigation */

#container{
margin: 0 auto; 
text-align: center;
background-color:#FFF;
font-family: helvetica, arial;
text-decoration: none; }

img.logo { 
text-align: center;
padding-top:0.5em;
width: 255px;
height: 255px; 
position: relative;
z-index:+1;}

#nav-menu {
position: absolute;
z-index: +1;
margin-top: 12em;
width: 101%;
background-color:#000000;
height: 2.8em;
text-align: center; }

#top ul {
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 0.5em;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center; }

#top ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin: auto; }


/*Nav Links*/   

#nav-menu li a:link {
font-size: 14px;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF; }

#nav-menu li a:hover, a:active {
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
color: #CCC; }

#nav-menu li a:visited {
font-size: 14px;
font-color:#0F0;
text-align: center;
color: #CCC; }

/* Body/ Section */ 

#home {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: -10.3em;
position: fixed;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center; }

#portfoliobody {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color:#FFF;
text-align: center;
overflow-y: auto; } 

#portfoliobody ul {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto; }   

#portfoliobody ul li {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center; }

#body {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 2.5em; }

#body ul {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto; }

#body ul li {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding-right: 2em; }

h2 {
float:left;
padding-left: 2em;
padding-top: 0.5em;
text-align: left;
font-family: helvetica, arial;
font-size: 22px;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: lighter; }

/* Contact Form CSS */

#form {
text-align: left;
font-family: helvetica, arial;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding-left: 24em; }

input, textarea {
background-color: #FFF; }

input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
width:125px;
color:#999;
background-color:#CCC; }

/* Footer */
/*Footer Bar*/  
footer {
width:101%;
margin: 0 auto; 
height: 2.8em;
background-color:#000; }

footer ul {
padding-right: 2em; }

footer nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
padding-left: 0.5em; 
float: right;
padding-right: auto;
padding-top: 5px; }

h3 {
float:left;
padding-left: 6em;
padding-right: 1em;
text-align: left;
font-family: helvetica, arial;
font-size: 20px;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration: none; }

h3 a:link {
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF; }

h3 a:hover, a:active {
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration:underline;
color: #CCC; }

h3 li a:visited {
font-size: 20px;
color: #CCC; }

/* Images */

.social-media { 
width: 35px;
height: 35px; }

.portfolio-menu {
width: 300px;
height: 300px; }    

.arrow {
float: left;
padding-top: 0.5em; }

.rollovers {
border: thin groove #000;
width: 283px; 
height: 294px; }

object { 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "base"? Header? Footer? Background? Body?

Comment: `Here is what I want:`  I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Basically I am having trouble aligning the top portion of my website. And getting the footer to sit at the bottom of the browser.

I want to center the logo and 2 navigation links around it, while centring them within the black bar.

All while it is still responsive.

Comment: Here is what I want: https://imageshack.com/i/0xovibp

Comment: Please isolate the problem. Don't just dump everything here and expect people to fix it for you.

Comment: The problem is I don't know where I went wrong, but someone me on here thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is this if you mean the container:

```
       body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

      }


        #container{
            margin: 0 auto; 
            width: whatever you want the width to be;
            text-align: center;
            background-color:#FFF;
            font-family: helvetica, arial;
            text-decoration: none; 
       }
```

You also have a body id in css which you don't use in your page. You can't use auto on body margin if you want the container div to align in the center. You dont need an id for the body either. The body is the first part of the DOM tree structure so just body is fine.

---

**EDIT:**

Check [this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yardpenalty/u9v6W/35/) out to get you started, but you will have to add margins and adjust height as you go. I suggest that you get familiar with Google Chrome Dev Tools by simply hitting f12 on any given web page. You can actually re-create a web page using this tool. Hope this helps!

Comment: this seems to have helped some, what about aligning the navigation links around the logo?

Comment: In that scenario you are going to have to use %s for most inner containers. What you will want is to set the outer div #container to 100% and then set two inner elements to which ever percentage you want for each inner element so that when the window resizes so does the divs. The header and sidebar are fixed elements. I actually suggest using f12 in chrome and observing the html layout to see if you can't replicate it. This tool is invaluable as a web dev. Hope this helps a little!

Comment: Thank you, I think so. The site I posted is what I designed in Photoshop and I have had a hard time finding something like it online to view the HTML.

Comment: I noticed that. You could also try using the clipping tool in windows and create images of the photoshop pics or just save the images and when you define the images widths and height the heights of the parent container should stretch to fit them. You're welcome.

Comment: Thanks! width: 100%; to make responsive?